# Multiple File Redirection with awk and find

Tags: shell-script, awk, find, io-redirection

I have some files in a directory. And I want to add some lines at top and end of file using `awk`.

Example: My `awk` command:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "line1\nline2" } { print $0 } END { print "line3\nline4" }' file |tee file
```

By using above command I can add `line1` & `line2` at the top & `line3`, `line4` at the end of `file`

**Now I want to do same action for all files that are exist in current directory.**

If I use :

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "line1\nline2" } { print $0 } END { print "line3\nline4" }' *
```

Then I get output on terminal screen but I **can't redirect to (or overwrite) all files**.

So, I tried following (To `find` + `awk`):

```
find -type f -exec awk 'BEGIN { print "line1\nline2" } { print $0 } END { print "line3\nline4" }' '{}' \;
```

By using above command I can print output on screen and hence **to overwrite files**,

I've tried following (To `find` + `awk` + overwrite with `tee`), but it getting error:

```
$ find -type f -exec awk 'BEGIN { print "line1\nline2" } { print $0 } END { print "line3\nline4" }' '{}' | tee '{}' \;
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Hence, How can I use **`awk`** to **overwrite** (i.e: with `|tee` or something else) **for all files** in current directory by command?

Comment: Like `sed -i`, GNU awk has an in-place editing plugin: `gawk -i inplace`.

Comment: @muru, `-i inplace` doesn't work for `BEGIN` and `END` statements though (works for BEGINFILE, but not ENDFILE)

Comment: Decision1: Use `sed` instead of `awk` (`sed -is -e '1 i\...' -e '$ a\...' *`). Decision2 Use loop `for` for each file in directory (`for file in *; do awk '...' "$file" | tee "$file" ; done`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU `awk` 4.1 or above:

```
find . -type f -exec awk '
   @load "inplace"
   BEGINFILE {
     inplace_begin(FILENAME, "")
     print "line1\nline2"
   }
   {print}
   ENDFILE {
     print "line3\nline4"
     inplace_end(FILENAME, "")
   }' {} +
```

Comment: What is meant by GNU `awk` : `awk`  or `gawk` ?

Comment: `Find: Only one instance of {} is supported with -exec ... +`

Comment: @Pandya, on GNU systems, `awk` will generally be the GNU implementation. On non-GNU systems, GNU `awk` may be available as `gawk`.

Comment: @Pandya, I can see only one instance of `{}` in the code I supplied. Are you sure you copied it properly?

Comment: I am using Trisquel GNU/Linux and only GNU awk version 4.0 is available for Belenos (latest) release. So I've to download GNU awk 4.1 from Ubuntu's utopic(14.10) branch!

Answer (score 2):

*Decision1*: Use GNU `sed` instead of `awk`

```
sed -i -e '1 i\line1\nline2' -e '$ a\line3\nline4' ./*
```

*Decision2*: Use loop for for each file in directory

```
for file in ./*
do
  awk '
       BEGIN { print "line1\nline2" }
       { print $0 }
       END { print "line3\nline4" }
      ' "$file" > "$file".tmp &&
    mv -f "$file".tmp "$file"
done
```

Comment: Note that the `sed` one won't work for empty files. About the second one, using a fixed file name in /tmp is dangerous and means `mv` will do a file copy if /tmp is a different filesystem. Also note that permissions and ownership won't be preserved and that would break symlinks.

Comment: As Stéphane Chazelas's answer uses only awk and resulting best one, I accepted it. Anyway +1